# Choosing an MCU in a time-effective way

Tags: microcontroller, component-selection

I'm spending a lot time figuring out which microcontroller I should choose for my projects.

*For example*, for one project I have the following requirements, in order of importance:

- I<sup>2</sup>S interface (for connecting at least 2 digital microphones, 4 preferred)
- At least 32kB RAM
- At least 40MHz clock
- Low power. Has to work for at least 24 hours on an 900mAh battery
- Should come in some kind of a board that I can work with by hand
- The board should be small, not much larger than a mobile phone
- This is a one-off project, so cost is not a major issue

*How does one go about finding a short-list of candidates that meet or exceed a given set of requirements (such as the above), and be sure that they haven't missed anything?*

Currently, I'm browsing through the [element-14 catalogue](http://www.element14.com/community/index.jspa) and opening up datasheets at random. This is a very slow process. Ideally, there would be some table where I could select what columns to display (such as RAM, clock speed, power consumption) and sort MCUs that match my criteria. Things may not be ideal, but surely people have smarter ways to browse the MCU market?

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what is wrong with the question.

Comment: The answer is "tediously" - it gets quicker with experience (as long as you spend some time each week staying abreast of what's available :)

Comment: Agree with Martin. In order to know what you're looking for you need to know what you're looking for. This gets old pretty fast. I mean, how many battery charge ICs are there now?

Comment: Start with the most unusual mandatory requirement - in your case the I2S as that's not as common in general purpose micros as it is on audio DSP chips etc.  That lets you disqualify a large percentage of the choices, making picking something that is convenient to use and affordable from the remainder an easier task.  Of course it can get tricky as you may be able to persuade some SPI-style serial engines to do passable I2S.

Comment: Looks like it's been closed because the scope of this website is "troubleshooting schematics" and not "finding components in order to design schematics".

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed. This question addresses a situation that happens to be very commonly. It is not a shopping or buying recommendation, as it doesn't talk about shipping/prices/where-to-buy, but merely about specifications and which-to-buy.

Answer (score 3):

Many manufacturers of microcontrollers have selection matrix pages on their web site to support just the type of thing you are needing. For manufacturers that support various broad categories of MCUs they segment their selection matrrix pages according to these categories. Atmel for example does this according to AVR, ARM and 8051. They quickly assume that you can easily make your selection choice based on these categories before trying to drill down further. The following shows some of the choices available in [Atmel's ARM selection](http://www.atmel.com/PFResults.aspx#%28data:%28area:%27%27,category:%2734864%5B33177%5D%27,pm:!%28%28i:8238,v:!%280,18%29%29,%28i:8394,v:!%280,18%29%29,%28i:8362,v:!%281,28%29%29,%28i:8282,v:!%280,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8%29%29%29,view:table%29,sc:1%29) matrix.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can quickly find links to the selection guides from various manufacturers by doing a [Google search with](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=microcontroller+selection+guide&oq=microcontroller+selec&gs_l=hp.1.2.0l3.2284.20612.0.23237.35.27.8.0.0.0.78.1289.27.27.0.les;cpsugrpq2high..0.0...1.1.j7CONNCkWS8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.cGE&fp=fc4acb3561d83b0d&biw=1370&bih=781) **microcontroller selection guide** as the search phrase. This will point to information from the likes of TI, NEC, NXP, Freescale, Analog Devices and Renesas to name but a few.

Answer (score 1):

Using websites like this can be very tedious work. I find that deciding what set of microcontrollers I'm interested in first and then using the manufacturers website to reduce to a shortlist helps (but only if that website is any good).

For example. If I'm interested in the Microchip PIC range, you can use their [Advanced Part Selector](http://www.microchip.com/maps/microcontroller.aspx) to make selection across 8/16/32 bit product ranges easier. Using a few of your parameters I reduce to a few parts, all in the dsPic, PIC24 or PIC32 range. I'm sure some of those have development boards. (PS: I2S is selective under the + submenu in *Digital Comm. Features*. No, I don't know why they do this!)

Other things to think about is the availability of development tools and ease of coding for the part family you are interested in. NXP have a range of ARM microcontrollers and there are many products like the [mbed](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9564) that might suit you. I'm afraid I haven't used I2S before so can't help you out there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the biggest factor is the support available, not the choice of micro. These days we are spoilt for choice for mid-spec micros which meet or exceed your requirements, the bigger issue is having a good dev/eval board available for good money ($50 rather than $500) and a toolchain/dev environment/debugger with supporting libraries etc. without spending huge sums on pro software (unless you have the budget for that too).

Unless your time is free, those factors will have a far greater impact than saving $0.20 per device in production.

Based on my current experience: Stay the hell away from Texas Instruments, unless you're buying a million devices a year they won't give you the time of day. I've had reasonable experience with Freescale (relatively!) and heard good stuff about NXP.

Comment: Yeah and end up using STM32F4... :)

Comment: They're very good, my boss has been playing with them. I think the IDE setup isn't completely smooth but they are excellent value and well supported.

Comment: We use STM32F2, which is really good. DMA is perfectly designed, many possibilities to choose how to transfer data, Ethernet MAC is capable of doing 95Mbps data transmissions. So far, no problems using STM32.

Comment: For TI I can say that although their methods of support are sometimes different, they will help you and you can get help. Perhaps you won't get an FAE to help you(I've seen it happen for small cases), but you will get help. Support is important, but if you know what you're doing, other criteria can be more important.

Comment: This is surprising feedback on TI: I've had precisely the opposite experience, they have been way better than any of the 4 other MCU manufacturers we deal with, at well-qualified, personalized support and design inputs even beyond the specific support request, on multiple product groups. We are not even a production house, so purchase estimates are in the dozens range, not millions. Yes, they do get very terse when hit with vague queries.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - we have had terrible experience, even though we are an established design outfit with a customer already selling reasonable numbers. TI won't talk to us because the volumes are too low (<100,000), their FAE for the device/application/sdk are in Taiwan and don't respond to mails, the TI wiki is a sea of stubs, broken links, and outdated/incomplete pages, the documentation is poor (assumes loads, doesn't explain actions) and the solution to everything is "use our forums" - which are full of unanswered questions from frustrated people who are in the same situation.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh ...to continue: HOWEVER, my experience with the TI MSP430 (a VERY different end of their lineup) has been (a bit) better, probably as it's far more popular / simple and they're actively promoting it. Downloading a 1.1Gb IDE for a 32k micro still seems like vast overkill, but at least it sort of worked with only mild frustration. TI's website is universally awful though.

Comment: @JohnU It might be worthwhile taking this precise feedback to whoever is account-managing your organization or segment for your geography within TI. While I agree that their web site leaves a lot to be desired, for the rest, our experience is in direct contrast.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - that's the point, **no-one** is managing anything, TI (UK) won't talk to us, send a sales guy, or sell dev tools to us because we aren't buying 100,000 chips per year.

Comment: @JohnU Oh rats! Have you tried escalating to the TI global design support team? A significant geography like the UK should not be neglected that badly, this needs serious rattling of their chains.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - TI's website doesn't give any way of contacting anyone, if you jump through all the "contact" links etc. it just spits you out with a standard "contact your FAE" / "ask on the forums" / "go away and stop bothering us"... even our local component sales rep could get no help out of them, neither could a friend who was dealing direct with their analogue dept.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7222/discussion-between-anindo-ghosh-and-john-u)